# Cordova/Phonegap custom build file name

Tags: cordova

When I create cordova/phonegap app build it generates file with predefined file name. For example when I run `cordova build android` I get files `Finance-debug-unaligned.apk` and `Finance-debug.apk`. Does cordova/phonegap support creating custom build file?

Comment: You could add a hook to just rename the file.

Comment: @MBillau please add as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to set up the name in the configuration files - it will just use whatever name you provided as the App ID when running cordova create command.

You could write a tiny hook that runs after build has completed to just rename the file.